# How to make nav bar common for all pages in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-thymeleaf

> I am using thymeleaf for  my front end design ,I create a nav bar and
> I want this nav bar work for all pages, my Requirement is make one nav
> bar and use this nav bar in every page ,with out define another nav
> bar in separate page .
> I create a nav bar inside my fragments folder that situated inside
> template folder
> When i call my nav bar in my index page it is not working
> Here is my code of index page
> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Coursel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/demo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <nav th:replace="/fragments/nav :: nav-front"></nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
 here my register form codes
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> nav.html

```
    <nav class="nav">
        <a class="nav-link active" th:href="@{/templates/index.html}">Active</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" th:href="@{/templates/index.html}">Register</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" th:href="@{/templates/index.html}">Login</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" th:href="@{/templates/index.html}">AboutUs</a>
 </nav>
```

> Here is  my project structure
> [image]

> I use IntelliJ IDEA as code editor.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, look into [Thymeleaf Layout Dialect](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect).

In short:

you create some `layout.html` in your `templates` folder. In it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
  <!-- all common head tags - meta etc. -->
  <title layout:title-pattern="$CONTENT_TITLE - $LAYOUT_TITLE">App name</title><!-- define title in your page template and it will be added too your app name, e.g. 'Home - My App' -->
</head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <!-- your nav here -->
  </nav>
  <section layout:fragment="content">
    <!-- don't put anything here, it will be replaced by the page contents -->
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And in you page templates:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorate="~{/path/to/layout.html}">
<head>
  <title>Page name</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section layout:fragment="content">
    <p>This will be added into your layout!</p>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

In order to make it work, you will need to add it to your `templateEngine()` bean definition:

```
@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver( thymeleafTemplateResolver() );
    templateEngine.addDialect( new LayoutDialect() );
    return templateEngine;
}
```

See [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-layout-dialect) to import this dialect using maven.